# Using pandas to combine excel file data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, glob

So, I am currently working on a project that spits out excel files containing data to make spectra (i.e. wavelength in one column, absorbance in the other). There are hundreds of excel files of this nature and I wish to condense them into a single file. This is mostly because column A (wavelength) is identical for all files, and only absorbance chances between files. Therefore, I would like to take columns A and B from the first file in a directory, write those to a new excel sheet, then take only column B from all remaining sheets and print those to the same output excel file. The code I currently have is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import glob
import numpy as np

def xlxtract():
    for filename in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    ExcelFile = filename[:-5]
    RosewoodData = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile + '.xlsx')
    Row = RosewoodData.values.tolist()
    ColDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength (nm)': [ x[0] for x in Row], 'Absorbance':[ x[1] for x in Row]})        
    Writer = ExcelWriter(filename[:-5] + 'TEST' + '.xlsx')
    ColDataFrame.to_excel(Writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
    Writer.save()

xlxtract()
```

I recognize that my code currently just reads all files and creates a separate file of a similar name while printing the exact same data to the new file and only adds a column name.

I am more than happy to look into the issue myself if anyone can even point me in the right direction on what to look into, but solutions to this are fine, too.

Comment: Read about merge in pandas where you can combine these with "wavelength" as primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that, as @Rahul mentioned above, what you need is function **merge**.  With it, you can combine dataframes based on a common column easily. You can see more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html). Also, for your specific case, I guess something around this should do the trick:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

def xlxtract():

    masterDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Wavelength (nm)"])
    minorDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Wavelength (nm)", "Absorvance"]) 

    for filename in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):

        minorDf = pd.read_excel(filename)

        masterDf = minorDf.merge(masterDf, how = 'outer', on= "Wavelength (nm)")

    masterDf.to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Comment: This produces KeyError: 'Wavelength'

Comment: It still doesn't seem to like wavelength for some reason. And it gives me the key error on line 1382, despite only having 11 lines of code.

Comment: It may be on line 1382 of your worksheet, I guess... If possible, copy and paste here the entire error message.

Comment: Scratch that. I got it now. Thank you for helping troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
df_list = []

for file in filelist:
    df_temp = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=0)
    df_list.append(df_temp)

df = pd.concat(df_list)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

This reads all the excel-files in to a separate DataFrame, with the first column (wavelength) as the index. After all DataFrames are created, pd.concat combines them in to 1 DataFrame, with the Wavelength column as the join key.

Comment: I don't think this would be the best solution... By doing this, you would have multiple dataframes allocated inside "df_list" at the same time. For a small amount of dataframes it's okay, but once you have a massive amount of dataframes, this could become a serious issue. Also, pd.merge function seems like a better way to do what he asked, since it's a function created for this purpose